# Find hamilton cycle in a directed graph reduced to sat problem

Tags: graphs, satisfiability, propositional-logic, hamiltonian-path, hamiltonian-circuit

I need to find a **Hamiltonian cycle** in a directed graph using propositional logic, and to solve it by sat solver. So after I couldn't find a working solution, I found a paper that describes how to construct a CNF formula to find an **Hamiltonian path**:

`Xi,j` - node j is in position i in the path

List of constraints:

1. Each node j must appear in the path
   `x1j ∨ x2j ∨ · · · ∨ xnj` - for every node j
2. No node j appears twice in the path `¬xij ∨ ¬xkj` for all i, j, k with i 6= k.
3. Every position i on the path must be occupied - `xi1 ∨ xi2 ∨ · · · ∨ xin` for each i
4. No two nodes j and k occupy the same position in the path - `¬xij ∨ ¬xik` for all i, j, k with j != k
5. Nonadjacent nodes i and j cannot be adjacent in the path - `¬xki ∨ ¬xk+1,j` for all (i, j) !∈ E and k = 1, 2, . . . , n − 1.

My question is, how can I find **Hamiltonian cycle** using these constraints? I understand that I need to check if there's a cycle (`v1==vn`), that's one thing (But I got constraint 2). Second, it's a directed graph and I don't know how can I assure that the vertices would be in the right order of the edges, I thought about this:

Every two nodes must have edges -  `Xki ^ Xk+1j` for each (i,j)∈ E and k = 1, 2, . . . , n − 1.

But it doesn't seem to work, any help would be appreciated.

EDIT

What I did was to add another constraint -

6. No edges from the set: (i,j)!∈ E that are the last and the first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the constraint that $x_{1j}=x_{nj}$ for all $j$, and make a special exception to constraint 2 so that you omit constraint 2 in the case where $i=1$ and $k=n$.

Everything works fine for a directed graph.  You just need to interpret constraint 5 appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose practical SAT solvers might search for and remove them, but I'd still suggest not giving it redundant variables - if you do know `v1==vn`, then just replace each instance of `vn` with `v1`.

If `n` is the number of vertices then you'd actually have `v0 == vn`, rather than `v1==vn`.

You can remove any one of {1.,2.,3.,4.}, since the combination {3.,4.} or {1.,2.}

will force X or its transpose respectively to be the graph of a function, and

for functions from a finite set to itself, [surjectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function) is equivalent to [injectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function).

Comment: Regarding your first sentence: I'd expect it won't make any difference, given how unit propagation works in modern SAT solvers -- but there's no harm in doing what you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is to extend the fifth constraint to all k = 1, ...,n and where there is k+1 in the constraint, add (mod n) operator.

This ensures that there is an edge from the last vertex to the first in the path, meaning it's a cycle.