# On equivalences to promise problem

Tags: complexity-classes

We know that under hierarchy collapse results GI is not NP complete.

Would there be any consequences if GI is equivalent to a promise version of an NP complete problem?

Comment: GI itself is not a promise problem, so I think you want to ask if GI is *equivalent* a PromiseNP-complete problem.

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow Would that show GI in NP$\cap$coNP from theorem $6$ here https://books.google.com/books?id=PsIbMEakyX8C&pg=PA267&lpg=PA267&dq=xSAT+NP+coNP&source=bl&ots=nIuaxebksr&sig=swBHrqfKjTNmuk3DqSWxdFWUpko&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj186C659LJAhVKPT4KHUAyDcgQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=xSAT%20NP%20coNP&f=false?

Answer (score 2):

No. Simple reductions from GI to SAT are efficiently invertible, so for any such reduction, GI is equivalent to SAT-that's-promised-to-be-in-the-range-of-the-reduction.

Comment: whats a simple reduction?

Comment: One would be: $\:$ create |V|^2 variables, assert [{1.,2.,3.,4.}](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/49593/12859), [for each non-edge in G$_0$ and each edge in G$_1$, assert that the endpoints of the non-edge are not sent to the endpoints of the edge], [for each edge in G$_0$ and each non-edge in G$_1$, assert that the endpoints of the edge are not sent to the endpoints of the edge] $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: I thought promise problems in NP are in $NP\cap coNP$ (https://books.google.com/books?id=EuguvA-w5OEC&pg=PA107&lpg=PA107&dq=xSAT+promise+problem)? So that would prove GI is that class?

Comment: ... That will be the case if and only if NP=coNP. ​ (If NP=coNP, then by syntacticness of NP, everything in promiseNP is in promise_coNP. ​ If NP≠coNP then taking any NP-complete language and [declaring that the empty string does not satisfy the promise] gives a promise problem in promiseNP which is not in promise_coNP.) ​ That does not prove membership of GI in coNP. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: The reference I gave you says any promise problem in NP reduces to xSAT. So does it mean we just have GI in PromiseNP$\cap$PromisecoNP?

Comment: Theorem $6$ here seems to say GI would be in NP$\cap$coNP https://books.google.com/books?id=PsIbMEakyX8C&pg=PA267&lpg=PA267&dq=xSAT+NP+coNP&source=bl&ots=nIuaxebksr&sig=swBHrqfKjTNmuk3DqSWxdFWUpko&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj186C659LJAhVKPT4KHUAyDcgQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=xSAT%20NP%20coNP&f=false.

Comment: Am I making a mistake?

Comment: The reference you gave me says "any promise problem in NP is Cook-reducible to xSAT." $\hspace{.93 in}$ No. ​ Why does it seem to say that? ​ Yes. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: I am not parsing it properly I believe. This is what I am thinking. We have GI. Suppose it is equivalent to PromiseNP complete problem. Then GI is cook-reducible to xSAT and hence in NP$\cap$coNP. Is my reasoning wrong?

Comment: On other hand GI is in NP so trivially in promiseNP and hence should be reducible to xSAT and hence in NP$\cap$coNP which is far beyond state of affairs. So I do not understand where I am wrong.

Comment: Yes. ​ GI is Cook-reducible to xSAT but is not known to be in coNP. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Can you give me a simple example of a smart reduction? Say GI reduces to a PromiseNP-complete problem via a smart reduction what does it supposed to be meaning and why is it difficult to get realistically?

Comment: What is the "it" in "it supposed"? ​ ​

Comment: What should the reduction look like for GI to be in NP intersect coNP in this case? Say I can convert GI to a PromiseNP complete problem via a smart reduction does it mean GI will be in NP$\cap$coNP then? would a smart reduction suffice for that? Why is it difficult to get a smart reduction?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32837/discussion-between-ricky-demer-and-turbo).

Comment: filler................... I am in chat.

Comment: Contrary to my last comment in chat, [there are somewhat-significant hardness results for GI](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.142.1448&rep=rep1&type=pdf), so with much less confidence, I'm now saying that I'm not aware of any barriers to putting GI in [rational-unifor](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.397.5306)m [T](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:T#tc0)C[1](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:A#ac1). ​ ​

Comment: but these hardness results have nothing to do with putting GI in coNP.